# Spring Kafka @SendTo Not Sending Headers

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I'm sending a message to Kafka using the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` and it's sending the message with a `kafka_correlationId`. However, when it hits my `@KafkaListener` method and forwards it to a reply topic, the headers are lost.

**How do I preserve the kafka headers?**

Here's my method signature:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "input")
@SendTo("reply")
public List<CustomOutput> consume(List<CustomInput> inputs) {
  ... /* some processing */
  return outputs;
}
```

I've created a `ProducerInterceptor` so I can see what headers are being sent from the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`, as well as from the `@SendTo` annotation. From that, another strange thing is that the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` is not adding the documented `kafka_replyTopic` header to the message.

Here's how the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` is configured:

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> cf) {
  ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
  return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
}

@Bean
public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Object, Object, Object> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> pf, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object> container) {
  return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I've added **Spring Cloud Sleuth** as a dependency as well, and the span/trace headers are there when I'm sending messages, but new ones are generated when a message is forwarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary headers from the request message are not copied to the reply message by default, only the `kafka_correlationId`.

Starting with version 2.2, you can configure a `ReplyHeadersConfigurer` which is called to determine which header(s) should be copied.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-send-to).

> Starting with version 2.2, you can add a `ReplyHeadersConfigurer` to the listener container factory. This is consulted to determine which headers you want to set in the reply message.

**EDIT**

BTW, in 2.2 the RKT sets up the replyTo automatically if there is no header.

With 2.1.x, it can be done, but it's a bit involved and you have to do some of the work yourself. The key is to receive and reply a `Message<?>`...

```
@KafkaListener(id = "so55622224", topics = "so55622224")
@SendTo("dummy.we.use.the.header.instead")
public Message<?> listen(Message<String> in) {
    System.out.println(in);
    Headers nativeHeaders = in.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.NATIVE_HEADERS, Headers.class);
    byte[] replyTo = nativeHeaders.lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC).value();
    byte[] correlation = nativeHeaders.lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID).value();
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(in.getPayload().toUpperCase())
            .setHeader("myHeader", nativeHeaders.lastHeader("myHeader").value())
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlation)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, replyTo)
            .build();
}

// This is used to send the reply - needs a header mapper
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaProducerFactory) {
    KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(kafkaProducerFactory);
    MessagingMessageConverter messageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setHeaderMapper(new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper("*")); // map all byte[] headers
    kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return kafkaTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> template) {
    return args -> {
        Headers headers = new RecordHeaders();
        headers.add(new RecordHeader("myHeader", "myHeaderValue".getBytes()));
        headers.add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "so55622224.replies".getBytes())); // automatic in 2.2
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("so55622224", null, null, "foo", headers);
        RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> future = template.sendAndReceive(record);
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> reply = future.get();
        System.out.println("Reply: " + reply.value() + " myHeader="
                + new String(reply.headers().lastHeader("myHeader").value()));
    };
}
```

Comment: My current `spring-kafka` version is 2.1.12... It's there any solution for an older version?

Comment: It's possible but you have to write more code. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: I have opted to just use KafkaTemplate to send it out then. The `@SendTo` annotation doesn't really do anything more than calling KafkaTemplate since I have to build the message myself anyways.